# Is there any way to make a static variable in Python?

Tags: python, scope, static, python-import, variable-assignment

I'm not exactly a noob but I'm also not the best Python dev. Recently I've been trying to make a program that creates a variable in the global scope of main.py, a function in main calls file2.foo(), and file2 imports main and edits the variable, and then main calls file3.bar(), where file3 imports that same variable and it would do things with the updated data from file2

I know that there's probably no real solution to this and that I should just use returns to update the var in main, but I was hoping that some of y'all might know of a way to make it static or have an easier solution for pass-by-reference

An example of what I'm trying to do:

main.py:

```
import file2, file3
var = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = 3
    file2.foo()
    # var should now be 6
    file3.bar()
    # var should now be 7
    print(var)
```

file2.py:

```
import main

def foo():
    main.var += 3
```

file3.py:

```
import main

def bar():
main.var += 1
```

I know that importing a file reinitializes it's variables like a class, but I also know that python classes can have static variables if all instances of the class are in the same file.
I've tried having a 4th file just for storing `var = 0` and having all three others import that, and I've also tried having a class in that 4th file set up like this:
4th file:

```
class a:
    static_var = 0
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.var = static_var
```

and then having all other files do `from file4 import a; global = a()` , then access it with `global.var += some_integer`

I've tried looking this up but as far as I can see no one else has this same problem.
Any help is appreciated, especially if it's just to tell me there's no way to do it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Your code looks correct. Each file should be imported just once. If you see different behavior, it is probably due to the circular imports (when the same file is imported a second time before it reaches the end and be added to the imported modules cache). You can use a debugger or add "prints" to debug it.

Comment: As noted, the imports cause the module to be loaded 1 time.  any future import just gets the imported information.   You are going to be trying to act on var before it is defined. when in main you import file2 and file3,  you have not yet caused var to be initialized.  you may want to move var=0 above the import?

Comment: fwiw,  you would benefit from reading in detail on how import works and handles (in detail) the referenced modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I necessarily support this approach, but you can achieve what you want by putting your "static variable" in a new file:

```
# main.py
import file1, file2, file3                                                                              
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("in main:", file1.var)                                                                             
    file2.foo()                                                                                         
    # var should now be 6                                                                               
    file3.bar()                                                                                         
    # var should now be 7                                                                               
    print("in main:", file1.var)
```

```
# file1.py
var = 0
```

```
#file2.py
import file1                                                                                            
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
def foo():                                                                                              
    file1.var = 6
```

```
# file3.py
import file1                                                                                            
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
def bar():                                                                                              
    file1.var += 1
```

You should benefit from reading how to import files in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html